# Python NamedTemporaryFile deleted without closing it

Tags: python, python-multithreading, temporary-files

I'm working with ZOPE and Python 2.4 and I have a problem according to a NamedTemporaryFile. I read that the file is deleted when it is closed, but somehow my file is deleted even if it's not.
I have a function that writes some xml specifications to a file with Python's threading.Thread. If the Thread is finished, 
 the filename is written to a session variable. I have another function that should open the file when the thread is finished. It's a JS function that checks every 10sec if the status is true. This is working so far, but when I try to open the file by it's filename it is already deleted.

```
def startWorker(self):    
    ts = time.time()
    self.threadID = ts
    sf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w+b", prefix=self.threadID, suffix=".zip", dir = "/test/tmp/")
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(sf, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    mythread = self.MyThread(target, self.threadID, zf, sf)
    mythread.join()            
    success = mythread.getSuccess()
    if success:
        self.setSessionVar('status', 'true')
        self.setSessionVar('filename', zf.filename)


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, target, threadID, *args):
        self.__threadID = threadID
        self.__target = target
        self.__zf = zf
        self.__sf = sf
        self.__args = args
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name=self.__threadID)
        self.start()

    def run(self): 
        try:
            self.zfout = self.__target(self.__zf, self.__sf, *self.__args)
            self.__success = True
            self.stop()
        except:
            self.stop()

    def stop(self):                       
        self.__keepAlive = False           

    def getsucces(self):
        return self.__success


def getFile(self): #JS function that is called every 10 sec
    filename = self.getSessionVar('filename', None)
    if self.getSessionVar('status', None) = 'true':
        open(filename) # file is already deleted here
    else:
        #do something
```

Can anyone give me a hint how to tell Python not to delete the file or help me with how Python is handling the tempfiles?
I'm working with python 2.4 so delete=false within NamedTemporaryFile is no option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *ignoring* the `zf` and `sf` objects in `MyThread.__init__()`; `*args` is left untouched.

Because your running thread is not adding additional references to the open file object, by the time the `startWorker` function finishes there are no more references left to the objects and they are deleted, taking the on-disk file with them.

Comment: I'm very sorry I think I was happy to fast. I changed my code above and still the file is deleted. Can it be that the reason is that I stop the Thread?

Comment: @user3891252: Yes, you are stopping `mythread`, why are you doing that if you wanted it to continue? I'd not use a thread here, by the way. I'd create a new temporary directory and have a periodic job delete such temporary directories automatically if they are older than a given time limit.

Comment: The problem is also the mythread.join() it is waiting for the thread to be finished and again by the time the startWorker finished I'm loosing the references. You are right I shouldn't use a Thread for this.

Comment: @user3891252: yes, the thread finishes, then your function ends and nothing is referencing the `MyThread` instance anymore. The reference count drops to 0, it is removed and nothing references the file objects anymore either, so those too are removed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) there are "two" times this file would be deleted;

> It will be destroyed as soon as it is closed (including an implicit
>   close when the object is garbage collected).